# Creating php template popup with jquery select menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popupwindow

I wanted to create a php template popup will appear on a small window by clicking jquery select menu.
For that reason I used select menu:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <select id="lunchBegins" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Select a Popup" onchange="javascript:handleSelect(this)">
        <option value="first_popup" value="1">Popup A</option>
        <option value="second_popup">Popup B</option>
      </select>
```

and javascript:

```
function handleSelect(elm)
{
window.location = elm.value+".php";
}
```

But it doesn't create a popup.it redirects me to the php file.Also I want that when it will open a popup, .php extension will be hidden.
Can you help me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Window.locations redirects you
Therefore you should use jquery .load method or ajax for loading your php file :)